# JSyn: Sine Wave on two channels

Tags: java, audio, trigonometry, jsyn

**I have figured the problem out before posting this question. Nevertheless I think this might help someone else, so I am posting it anyway. If anyone knows a better or more elegant way to do this, please post an answer. If I agree, I will of course accept your answer. Here is my original problem:**

I am trying to get the following to work with [JSyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/):

I want to play an 800Hz sine wave on two channels and switch on or off the individual channels whenever I want. So, for instance, I want the following sequence:

```
 time  0s  0.3s      0.8s   1s            1s  1.1s    1.5s
 left  |--------------------|              |-----------|  
 right |----|         |------------------------|
```

I can generate the sine wave on either one, or both channels, but I have not figured out how to turn them on/off. Here is some code:

```
import com.jsyn.JSyn;
import com.jsyn.Synthesizer;
import com.jsyn.unitgen.LineOut;
import com.jsyn.unitgen.SineOscillator;

public class MusicTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playSound();
    }

    public static void playSound() {
        Synthesizer synth = JSyn.createSynthesizer();
        try {
            synth.start();
            SineOscillator sineOsc1 = new SineOscillator(500, 0.2);
            SineOscillator sineOsc2 = new SineOscillator(500, 0.2);
            LineOut lineOut= new LineOut();

            synth.add(lineOut);
            synth.add(sineOsc1);
            synth.add(sineOsc2);

            sineOsc1.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 0); // left channel
            sineOsc2.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 1); // right channel

            lineOut.start();

            sineOsc1.start(); // start left
            sleep(1000);
            sineOsc2.start(); // after 1s, start right
            sleep(1000);
            sineOsc1.stop(); // after 1s, stop left
            sleep(1000);
            sineOsc2.stop(); // after 1s, stop

            lineOut.stop();
        } finally {
            synth.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the first example did not work is because JSyn "pulls" data through connected unit generators.

The start() method add a unit to a list of units that are executed directly by the engine. You start() the end of a chain, eg the LineOut.  When a unit executes it asks for data from any units connected to its inputs. Those units, in turn, ask for data from any units connected to them. This guarantees that the units execute in an order that minimizes latency. JSyn checks for circular connections to prevent infinite loops.

Even though you stop()ped the SineOscillators, the LineOut was still pulling on them. So they made sound.

Instead of calling start() or stop() on the oscillators, call setEnabled(f). This will block the pulling of data.  Try this code snippet in your first example:

```
sineOsc1.setEnabled( false ); // begin disabled
sineOsc2.setEnabled( false );
lineOut.start();

sineOsc1.setEnabled(true); // start left
sleep(1000);
sineOsc2.setEnabled(true); // after 1s, start right
sleep(1000);
sineOsc1.setEnabled( false ); // after 1s, stop left
sleep(1000);
sineOsc2.setEnabled( false ); // after 1s, stop
```

Another approach is to use one oscillator and connect it through a Multiply unit to each channel of the LineOut.  Then you can turn on or off the sine on that channel by multiplying by 1.0 or 0.0.  This allows you to multiply by a scalar, eg. 0.5, if you want to be half on.

```
    sineOsc ---> multiply1 ---> lineOut(0) // left channel
            `--> multiply2 ---> lineOut(1) // right channel
```

I realize the setEnabled() and start() methods are not well documented. I will fix that now.

Comment: Thanks philburk for that very nice explanation. Your solution certainly looks cleaner than mine. I will try it out tonight.

Comment: Ok, I was able to test it and your solution works perfectly. (Actually, I didn't expect otherwise from the creator of JSyn. ^^) Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not try to turn on/off the sine wave, but just use two `LineOut`. Like this:

```
public static void playSound() {
    Synthesizer synth = JSyn.createSynthesizer();
    try {
        synth.start();
        SineOscillator sineOsc1 = new SineOscillator(500, 0.2);
        LineOut lineOut1 = new LineOut();
        LineOut lineOut2 = new LineOut();

        synth.add(lineOut1);
        synth.add(lineOut2);
        synth.add(sineOsc1);

        sineOsc1.output.connect(0, lineOut1.input, 0); // connect to left channel
        sineOsc1.output.connect(0, lineOut2.input, 1); // connect to right channel

        lineOut1.start(); // start left
        sleep(1000);
        lineOut2.start(); // after 1s, start right
        sleep(1000);
        lineOut1.stop(); // after 1s, stop left
        sleep(1000);
        lineOut2.stop(); // after 1s, stop
    } finally {
        synth.stop();
    }
}
```

I don't know if that is the most elegant solution, but it works really great. I hope this is of help for someone else.